# Mongorestore problem Authentication failed

Tags: mongodb

```
mongorestore -h ds121312.mlab.com:21312 -d heroku_jzxndzbk -u heroku_jzxndzbk -p xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  dump/Loc8r
```

***Error:***

```
2019-12-20T11:36:55.931-0500    error connecting to host: could not connect to server: connection() : auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRA
M-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.
```

I am following along "Getting MEAN" text by Holmes/Harber - pg 152.

Any suggestions?  Thank you

Comment: Jus a thought, but I've had issues connecting to the db, if the tools version was incompatible with the database. Make sure both mongo-tools and your mongodb install are compatible

Answer (score 10):

You must also specify which database you are using for authentication, e.g., `--authenticationDatabase admin`.

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-authenticationdatabase